# erro na instalaçao do kivy python

Tags: python-3.x

Nao to conseguindo fazer a instalaçao da biblioteca kivy do python3.11, os pacotes funciono normal mas na instalaçao do kivy aparece o seguinte erro.
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aijc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!

Talvez esteja relacionado à versão do Python mesmo. A ultima versão estável do Kivy foi lançada em: 6 de mar. de 2022. Então provavelmente ainda não tem suporte ao python 3.11.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).